# trying to install pm2 via npm -g but not installed after finished

Tags: node.js, pm2

When we try and install pm2 it doesnt show any pertidular errors, but its not available afterwards.

```
npm install pm2 -g

npm WARN install Could't install optional dependency: Unsupported
C:\c\Users\westd\.node\pm2-dev -> C:\c\Userswestd\.node\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2-dev
C:\c\Users\westd\.node\pm2 -> C:\c\Userswestd\.node\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
C:\c\Users\westd\.node\pm2 -> C:\c\Users\westd\.node\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2
C:\c\Users\westd\.node\pm2-dev -> C:\c\Users\westd\.node\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm
2-dev
C:\c\Users\westd\.node
└─┬ pm2@1.0.0
 └── ikt@0.0.0  (git+http://ikt.pm2.io/ikt.git#3325a3e39a502418dc2e2e4bf21529cb
bde96228)
```

then i try and run pm2, and it doesn't exist??

help needed?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9204#issuecomment-174223597

Comment: @mostruash - I will try 'the later part of that link' tomorrow, but given that why would pm2 not be available afterwards??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the config file had been set with a weird location, so it was installing to C:/c/users/me .....

we altered this and it worked correctly.